# ASP.NET MVC Razor, Html.BeginForm, using statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

For an ASP.NET MVC application, can someone explain to me why calls to `Html.BeginForm` begin with the statement `@using`?

Example -

> @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
>
> ```
>    //Stuff in the form
> ```
>
> }

I thought `@using` statements are for including namespaces.
Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of `IDisposable`objects. Since the `BeginForm` helper implements the `IDisposable` interface you can use the `using` keyword with it. In that case, the method renders the closing `</form>` tag at the end of the statement. You can also use the `BeginForm` without `using` block, but then you need to mark the end of the form:

```
@{ Html.BeginForm(); }
    //Stuff in the form
@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

Answer (score 4):

[`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx) as a statements are used to define scope of IDisposable object.

```
@using (var form = Html.BeginForm()) {
    //Stuff in the form

} // here Dispose on form is invoked.
```

Html.BeginForm return object that during dispose render closing tag for a form: `</form>`

[`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sf0df423(v=vs.80).aspx) for including namespace is directive.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `using` with Html.BeginForm, the helper emits closing tag and opening tag during the call to BeginForm and also the call to return object implementing `IDisposable`.

When the execution returns to the end of (Closing curly brace) using statement in the view, the helper emits the closing form tag. The `using` code is simpler and elegant.

Its not mandatory that you should use `using` in combination with `Html.BeginForm`.

You can also use

```
@{ Html.BeginForm(); }
   <input type="text" id="txtQuery"/>
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```