# @using block before @Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering why enclose @Html.BeginForm() in @using block like below. Does it matter if I don't use @using block?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [ASP.NET MVC Razor, Html.BeginForm, using statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935707/asp-net-mvc-razor-html-beginform-using-statement)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does it matter if I don't use @using block?

Yes, it will matter. The BeginForm method returns an IDisposable and in its Dispose method it renders the closing `</form>` tag. So if you don't place it in a `using` statement you will have to generate the closing form tag yourself:

```
@Html.BeginForm()
...
@Html.EndForm()
```

which is uglier.